# alexa skill account linking fails at token endpoint

Tags: oauth, alexa-skills-kit

alexa skill doesnot send "client secret" in the request to the token endpoint which fails the account linking in my OAuth server.
The request body contains : 
{ 'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
'code': '*******',
   'redirect_uri': 'https://pitangui.amazon.com/api/skill/***',
'client_id': '******' }

Comment: Can you add the query error ? Wich endpoint do you use ? PHP ? AWS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client secret should not be sending from the Alexa URL but it used for identify the request as coming from Alexa

Secret ID => "A credential you provide that lets the Alexa service authenticate with the Access Token URI. This is combined with the Client ID to identify the request as coming from Alexa."